# How can I automatically backup old pictures to OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, photos, backup

I know you can backup pictures automatically, and once backup is activated all pics go to OneDrive.

But even after waiting a a few days under Wi-Fi old pictures have not been copied to OneDrive: is there a way to do so without going to each picture and save it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Nokia 1020 I can select multiple pictures and then tell to save all the selected items to OneDrive.

Comment: Only problem is that this way photos are send to the "Mobile Upload" folders, not the backup (Pictures/Camera Roll) one